# How to load background-image url with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello is a possible to get background-image url from different page with ajax?
I tried this but it seems that does not work. Thank you for help.

```
var test = jQuery('#el').load('https://www.example.com/somepage/' .some-element).css('background-image');
console.log(test);
```

or

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.example.com/somepage/',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log("Status: "+status+"\nData: "+data);
            result = data;
            var img = jQuery('.some-element').css('background-image');
            console.log(img);
        }
});
```

Both is same. How to get background-image url from another page with javascript?

Comment: This doesn't look like valid JS. Where is the "complete" callback function?

Comment: I think that both code is valid js, but maybe u are right.. Can you help me to fix this please?

Comment: All AJAX requests are subject to the same-origin policy so the proper CORS header need to be set by the server to allow the client to load images via this way. I would recommend to simply change the CSS rule to make the client load the image the proper way: `$('.some-element').css('background-image', 'url(https://2.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TS1200x900~sample_galleries/9077940471/7146948694.jpg)');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not ajax but its solution what u proably need.

```
function loadBackground(url, query) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.onload = function () {
            var el = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector(query);
            if (el) {
                var style = iframe.contentWindow.getComputedStyle(el);
                resolve(style.getPropertyValue("background-image"));
            } else {
                reject(new Error("Element not found"));
            }
            document.body.removeChild(iframe);
        };
        iframe.style.width = 0;
        iframe.style.height = 0;
        iframe.style.border = 0;
        iframe.src = url;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    });
}

loadBackground("https://www.example.com/somepage/", ".some-element").then(function (bg) {
    console.log(bg);
});
```